# Yii Bootstrap TbGridView

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, frameworks, yii-extensions, yii-widgets

For some reason my filtering isn't working correctly inconjunction with the pager on my Yii site, I have the following view which uses the **Yii Bootstrap TbGridView widget** to display some tabular data and have the ability to filter on different options as well as display a pager if more than 10 rows are displayed.

When I use filtering it works ok, however if I use the filtering and then navigate to another page of the pager (e.g page 2 or 3 for instance) the $_GET AJAX request breaks.

When I open this AJAX request URL in a new tab in Mozilla irefox it displays the following:

```
The connection was reset
```

When I view the URL it generates I can see the problem with what is going on, below is the URL that is generated, with the 2nd URL being the correct URL structure that it should be for it to work.

```
// 'broken' url     
http://dev.local/dev/shop/products/admin/ShopProducts%5Bproduct_name%5D//ShopProducts%5BemailNotification%5D//ShopProducts%5Bemail_user%5D//ShopProducts%5Bactive%5D//ShopProducts%5Binstant_win%5D//ShopProducts%5Bmulti_buy%5D//ShopProducts%5Bprice%5D//ShopProducts%5Bquantity%5D//ShopProducts_page/2/ajax/shopproducts-grid/hidden?ajax=shopproducts-grid
```

This is the structure that I am expecting (this works when I manually past this into the browser)

```
http://dev.local/dev/shop/products/admin?ShopProducts%5Bproduct_name%5D=&ShopProducts%5BemailNotification%5D=&ShopProducts%5Bemail_user%5D=&ShopProducts%5Bactive%5D=&ShopProducts%5Binstant_win%5D=&ShopProducts%5Bmulti_buy%5D=1&ShopProducts%5Bprice%5D=&ShopProducts%5Bquantity%5D=&ShopProducts_page/2/ajax/shopproducts-grid/hidden?ajax=shopproducts-grid
```

The problem is for some reason it is replacing the string '=&' in the URL with '//' and this is causing it to break.

I cannot understand why it is doing this, any ideas?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="inner">
    <?php

    $data = $model->search();
    $hidden = (bool)CHttpRequest::getParam('hidden');

    $filterBtn = $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'icon'          => 'filter',
            'size'          => 'small',
            'label'         => $model->paging ? 'View All' : 'View Less',
            'htmlOptions'   => array('class'=>'pull-right', 'style'=> 'margin:0 0 20px 10px;'),
            'url'           => $model->paging ? array("/dev/shop/products/admin/paging/0/hidden/{$hidden}") : array("/dev/shop/products/admin/hidden/{$hidden}")
        ), true);

    echo ($filterBtn);

        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
            'id'            => 'shopproducts-grid',
            'type'          => 'striped bordered condensed',
            'dataProvider' => $data,
            'filter'        => $model,
            'template'      => '{summary}{items}{pager}',
            'template'      => 2 > ShopProductsController::PAGE_SIZE ?
                            '<div class="row-fluid"><div class="pull-right">'.$filterBtn.'</div><div class="pull-right" style="padding-top:5px;">{summary}</div></div>{items}<div class="row-fluid"><div class="pull-left">{pager}</div><div class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 20px;">'.$filterBtn.'</div></div>':
                            '<div class="row-fluid"><div class="pull-right">{summary}</div></div>{items}<div class="row-fluid"><div class="pull-left">{pager}</div></div>',
            'selectableRows'=>1,
            'columns'       => array(
                array(
                    'header'            => 'Image',
                    'value'             => 'CHtml::image($data->displayImageUrl, $data->product_name, array("class"=>"grid-image"))',
                    'type'              => 'raw',
                ),
                array(
                    'header'            => 'Name',
                    'name'              => 'product_name',
                    'value'             => 'CHtml::link($data->product_name,array("update","id"=>$data->getPrimaryKey()))',
                    'type'              => 'raw'
                ),
                array(
                    'name'              => 'emailNotification',
                ),
                array(
                    'header'            =>  'Notify User',
                    'name'              => 'email_user',
                    'value'             => 'CHtml::tag("i", array("class" => ($data->email_user == 1) ? "icon-font-ok" : "icon-font-remove"))',
                    'filter'            => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'email_user', array(0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'), array('prompt' => 'All')),
                    'type'              => 'raw',
                    'headerHtmlOptions' => array('class' => 'align-center'),
                    'htmlOptions'       => array('class' => 'align-center'),
                ),

                array(
                    'header'            =>  'Active',
                    'name'              => 'active',
                    'value'             => 'CHtml::tag("i", array("class" => ($data->active == 1) ? "icon-font-ok" : "icon-font-remove"))',
                    'filter'            => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'active', array(0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'), array('prompt' => 'All')),
                    'type'              => 'raw',
                    'headerHtmlOptions' => array('class' => 'align-center'),
                    'htmlOptions'       => array('class' => 'align-center'),
                ),
                array(
                    'header'            => 'Instant Win',
                    'name'              => 'instant_win',
                    'value'             => 'CHtml::tag("i", array("class" => ($data->instant_win == 1) ? "icon-font-ok" : "icon-font-remove"))',
                    'filter'            => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'instant_win', array(0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'), array('prompt' => 'All')),
                    'type'              => 'raw',
                    'headerHtmlOptions' => array('class' => 'align-center'),
                    'htmlOptions'       => array('class' => 'align-center'),
                ),
                array(
                    'header'            => 'Multi-Buy',
                    'name'              => 'multi_buy',
                    'value'             => 'CHtml::tag("i", array("class" => ($data->multi_buy == 1) ? "icon-font-ok" : "icon-font-remove"))',
                    'filter'            => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'multi_buy', array(0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'), array('prompt' => 'All')),
                    'type'              => 'raw',
                    'headerHtmlOptions' => array('class' => 'align-center'),
                    'htmlOptions'       => array('class' => 'align-center'),
                ),
                array(
                    'name'              => 'price',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'              => 'quantity',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'              => 'organisation_name',
                    'visible'           => ((user()->hasAuth(Group::GROUP_ADMIN, 'equal')) && (!user()->hasState('view_org'))),
                    'filter'            => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'organisation_id', CHtml::listData(Organisation::model()->leaChildren, 'organisation_id', 'organisation_name'), array('prompt'=>'All Schools')),
                ),
                array(
                    'class'             => 'application.widgets.bootstrap.TbButtonGroupEx',
                    'delete'            => false,
                    'header'            => 'Actions',
                    'filter'            => CHtml::link('<i class="icon icon-remove"></i><br/>Remove Filters', array($this->defaultAction, 'clearFilters'=>1), array('class'=>'remove-filters')),
                    'template'          => '{view}{update}',
                    'headerHtmlOptions' => array(
                        'style'             => 'text-align:center; width:50px;'
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ));
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: & is replaced by / because you are using "Path" formatting

Comment: is that something i need to alter within this view above?

Comment: no it will be in your config/main.php in under 'urlManager' ->            'urlFormat'=>'path', change it to Get see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#creating-urls for more info

Answer (score 0):

The url problem associated with CUrlManager: as default if `urlFormat` set to `path` `('urlFormat' => 'path')` yii appends GET params. To solve this you can set `appendParams` to `false`:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'appendParams'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
                ....
    ),
),
```